# Visibility of protected field

Tags: java

```
package p1;

public class MyClass1 {

      protected static  String str = "ss1";

    }

package p2;

import p1.MyClass1;

public class MyClass2 extends MyClass1 {

     public static void test(){

         MyClass1 mc1 = new MyClass1();

         System.out.println(mc1.str); 

         }

}
```

As I understand it, the print statement will not work if the String is declared as protected  as it is not visible from a different package. But why does it work when is declared as static protected ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*static* modifier has nothing to do with visibility, so nothing will change. You can't access *protected* member (i.e. field, method) from different package, no matter if it's static or not.

But in your case, MyClass2 extends MyClass1. You can access protected members from superclass. Still, *static* has nothing to do with this.

EDIT:

Well, this is a very interesting case because there are involved two separate things:
1) Accessing protected members from subclass in different package,
2) Syntax trick allowing you to access static (class) members like instance members.

I will extend your example to show what actually are you doing in this code:

```
package p1;

public class MyClass1 {

    protected String protectedString = "example";

    protected static String protectedStaticString = "example";

}

package p2;

import p1.MyClass1;

public class MyClass2 extends MyClass1 {

    public void testProtected() {

        MyClass1 otherMC1 = new MyClass1();
        MyClass2 otherMC2 = new MyClass2();

        String testProtected;

        testProtected = this.protectedString; // OK, protectedString is inherited, so it's instance member of this class
        testProtected = super.protectedString; // OK, it's also instance member of superclass

        testProtected = otherMC1.protectedString; // ERROR. You can't access protected members of other instance of superclass
        testProtected = otherMC2.protectedString; // OK. As it's inherited member of MyClass2, you can access it if it belongs to other instance of your class

    }

    public void testProtectedStatic() {

        MyClass1 otherMC1 = new MyClass1();
        MyClass2 otherMC2 = new MyClass2();

        String testProtectedStatic;

        testProtectedStatic = this.protectedStaticString; // OK - syntax trick
        testProtectedStatic = super.protectedStaticString; // OK - syntax trick

        testProtectedStatic = otherMC1.protectedStaticString; // OK - syntax trick
        testProtectedStatic = otherMC2.protectedStaticString; // OK - syntax trick

        testProtectedStatic = MyClass1.protectedStaticString; // OK - you can access protected static members from superclass
        testProtectedStatic = MyClass2.protectedStaticString; // OK - this also static member of your class
    }

}
```

Now, what is 'syntax trick'. Compiler allows you accessing static members like they were instance members:

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass();
Object o = mc.STATIC_FIELD;
```

But what will be actually compiled to the bytecode:

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass();
Object o = MyClass.STATIC_FIELD;
```

Accessing static members in this way is considered as bad practice because it's misleading. You should always access static members in a static way to avoid confusion while reading code.

This is what's goin on in your case. There were static field accessed in a non-static way, so it looked like instance field. When you removed *static* modifier, it became an instance member. The way this field is accessed changed, but you didn't notice that because of your *object.staticField* syntax.

Comment: That's true, I've just noticed this and I've edited the answer.

Comment: You can access from different package through inheritance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But then why would it not work if String str is protected only? I am still accessing it from the subclass.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what exactly works for you and what doesn't. Could you please show examples, and tell what error do you get?

Comment: Sorry I did not make myself clear. The code above compiles fine. But, if I change the access modifier of the String ss from "static protected" to "protected", I get a compile time error: str has protected access in MyClass1
  System.out.println(mc1.str);
                       ^

Comment: OK, now I understand what's going on. Explanation is quite long so I've edited my answer to show you why do you get this error.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out, static has nothing to do with visibility.

In your case, 'str' is marked as protected, which means that 2 types of classes can see it :
- classes in the same package
- classes that extend MyClass1

Your code works because MyClass2 extends MyClass1.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with it being *static* or not. you can access the member because MyClass2 extends MyClass1

Answer (score 0):

Here is an interesting rule: You can access protected instance variables defined in a superclass, but you cannot access private instance variables in a subclass of that class with the private instance variables. e.g.

```
public class Super {
   private String str;
}

public class Sub extends Super {
    public void getStr(){
        return str; // not allowed.
    }
}
```

However, if the following was used, then this is allowed:

```
public class Super {
   protected String str;
}

public class Sub extends Super {
    public void getStr(){
        return str; // allowed.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- `public` means it's visible to all classes.
- `protected` means it's visible to the package *and all sub-classes*.
- (no modifier) means it's visible to the package only.
- `private` means it's only visible in its own class.

See [Controlling Access to Members of a Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) for more info.